# cookieless site in IIS

Tags: iis, cookieless

how can i set site in iss so that it will be cookieless?
i'm using asp and not asp.net

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not use sessions, which use a temporary cookie (and obviously not use cookies).

This is not a setting/config of the site/web server, but a programming method.

Comment: Perhaps a question more for Stackoverflow rather than Serverfault?

Comment: so if i host in a domin onlu css,png files i don't need to do anything?

Comment: Yes, only javascript and dynamic server page (php, asp, etc) can create a cookie.